# How to parse a query string in React WITHOUT React Router?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to parse a query string in a React component that is not in a Route. Therefore, I can't use this.props.location.search. How would I go about doing this?

I tried window.location.search but it parses as null.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <HashRouter>
     <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page2} />
      </Switch>
      <OldLink />
     </div>
    </HashRouter>
   );
  } 
}
```

This is the layout of my App component, I'm trying to parse the query string in the Navbar component, which isn't in a route.

Comment: If it is not in the Route then how will you get it in URL?

Comment: could you give a sample snippet? to make it clear.

Comment: So is it not possible then?

Comment: Can you share your sample URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `window.location.search` should work. However you don't need to use it.

You can decorate the `Navbar` component with `withRouter`.

See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

Answer (score 1):

Do as @keul said and use withRouter(NavBar) to get access to props.location. An alternative would be to use window.location.pathname.

Then you can parse it however you want or use React Router's [matchPath](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/matchPath).

Comment: Why `pathname`? He want to inspect a query string parameter

Comment: Could be. I interpreted it as wanting to parse a route like "/path/:pageId" because that's the usual thing to do with react-router and window.location.search returns null for him.